# iOS: AFNetworking VS. NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: ios, timeout, afnetworking, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I've been using `AFNetworking 2.0` on my iOS App to regularly send HTTP requests and get data from a server and it works fine. But I needed to download a big file from time to time from this server (the same) so I decided to use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` for that purpose.

The issue I have is that during a background downloading, and while my App is still in foreground, all the requests sent by the App using `AFNetworking` timeout.

On the server side, I can see that on the 25 simultaneous sockets that can be opened, one is taken by the background downloading and the rest is available so the server is still able to receive HTTP requests.

Any idea?